# UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning iOS 11 Offset issue

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I am trying to do custom transition and I want a view to come in to focus from bottom. But as seen in the video, the snapshot of the view is not exactly equal to what is rendered in the viewcontroller and so it gives a jerk at the end.

Video Link:
https://gfycat.com/RewardingSplendidBoar

You can see give button giving a little jerk. This does not happen in iOS 10.

I have already added 
toVC.view.setNeedsLayout()
toVC.view.layoutIfNeeded()
but still no avail.

Here is my code:

```
func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        var selected: IndexPath?
        if collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.count == 0 {
            selected = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
        }
        else {
            selected = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?[0]
        }
        print("Selected cell: \(String(describing: selected?.row))")
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: selected!)
        let container: UIView? = transitionContext.containerView
        var fromVC : UIViewController;
        var toVC : UIViewController;
        if isPresenting {
            fromVC = (transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from) as! ViewController)
            toVC = (transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to) as! EventDetailVC)
            toVC.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }else{
            fromVC = (transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from) as! EventDetailVC)
            toVC = (transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to) as! ViewController)
        }

        let fromView: UIView? = fromVC.view
        let toView: UIView? = toVC.view

        let beginFrame: CGRect? = container?.convert((cell?.contentView.bounds)!, from: cell?.contentView)
        var endFrame: CGRect = transitionContext.initialFrame(for: fromVC)
        endFrame = toView?.frame ?? CGRect.zero
        var move: UIView? = nil
        var iconBack: UIView? = nil
        var btnGive: UIView? = nil
        var transitionDuration: CGFloat
        if isPresenting {
            transitionDuration = CGFloat(self.duration)
            toView?.frame = endFrame
            move = toView?.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true)
            (toVC as! EventDetailVC).ivBack.alpha = 1
            iconBack = (toVC as! EventDetailVC).ivBack?.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true)
            (toVC as! EventDetailVC).btnGive.alpha = 1
            btnGive = (toVC as! EventDetailVC).btnGive?.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true)
            move?.frame = beginFrame!
            move?.alpha = 0.0
            container?.addSubview(move!)
            container?.addSubview(iconBack!)
            container?.addSubview(btnGive!)
        }
        else {
            transitionDuration =  CGFloat(self.duration)
            move = fromView?.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true)
            move?.frame = (fromView?.frame)!
            fromView?.removeFromSuperview()
            container?.addSubview(move!)
        }

        if isPresenting {
            toVC.view.setNeedsLayout()
            toVC.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            var frame =  (toVC as! EventDetailVC).ivBack.frame;
            frame.origin.x =  (toVC as! EventDetailVC).view.frame.size.width
            iconBack?.frame = frame
            var frame1 =  (toVC as! EventDetailVC).btnGive.frame
            frame1.origin.y =  (toVC as! EventDetailVC).view.frame.size.height
            btnGive?.frame = frame1

            UIView.animate(withDuration: TimeInterval(transitionDuration) , animations: {() -> Void in
                move?.frame =  (toVC as! EventDetailVC).imageView.frame
                move?.alpha = 1.0
                cell?.alpha = 0.0
                iconBack?.frame = (toVC as! EventDetailVC).ivBack.frame
                btnGive?.frame = (toVC as! EventDetailVC).btnGive.frame
            }, completion: {(_ finished: Bool) -> Void in
                iconBack?.removeFromSuperview()
                 btnGive?.removeFromSuperview()
                move?.removeFromSuperview()
                toView?.frame = endFrame
                container?.addSubview(toView!)
                transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
            })
        }
        else {
            cell?.isHidden = false
            cell?.alpha = 0.0

            UIView.animate(withDuration: TimeInterval(transitionDuration), animations: {
                move?.frame = beginFrame!
                move?.alpha = 0.0
                cell?.alpha = 1.0
            }, completion: { (_ finished: Bool) in
                cell?.isHidden = false
                transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should post some code.

Comment: Did you solved it? I'm having the same issue